# How to compile a LaTeX document?

Tags: compiling, windows

Up until now, I've just been using LyX for all my LaTeX needs. Now I have a `.tex` file and I need to compile it (turn to pdf). How do I do this on Windows XP? Obviously I have LaTeX installed (MikTeX).

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use an editor that integrates with TeX, like [TeXworks](http://tug.org/texworks/). However, as I haven't compiled any TeX file on Windows for years, I leave this question for someone else to answer in detail.

Comment: Amir, you seem to be a bit confused about the difference between TeX and LaTeX. I've edited your question to make it more accurate,  but please have a look at [this other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex) that explains the difference more clearly. Unless, of course, your file is really a TeX document, then please make that clear in your question.

Comment: is there a Apple/mac os solution?

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, there are plenty. Lyx is available for mac as well. You should start by reading the following intro: https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-beginners-guide-to-using-tex-in-os-x--mac-45177

Answer (score 54, accepted):

one way of doing this is using the command line by entering `pdflatex yourfilename.tex` (assuming MikTex is in your path - just give it a try).

Another way would include installing software such as [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) or [TeXworks](http://tug.org/texworks/) which will let you open/edit/compile a `.tex` file from within an editor environment.

A third way could be to import it into LyX and then compile with LyX as usual.

**Edit:** See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Comment: I'd upvote, except that you seem to be recommended importing into Lyx as a reasonable possibility, a path of pain for novices.

Comment: Is File > Import > LaTeX (plain) in Lyx broken?

Comment: @Tormad: Lyx has to compile the Latex, and this process might fail since Lyx has to infer Latex's structure - Lyx only promises to compile what it calls "clean" Latex, and put what it can't parse into Tex tags.  This is the right thing to do, but I wouldn't recommend it to beginners.  BTW, if you want to draw a user's attention to your comment, put @WWW in your comment, where WWW is at least the first three letters of their screen name.

Comment: is there a Apple/mac os solution?

Comment: A middle complex LaTeX  will be imported basically as unusable garbage in LyX. While LyX to LaTeX always works nicely, even import a file just produced by LyX  could be a pain.

Answer (score 6):

I'd take a more integrated approach than the other answer.

## Use build tools

Look on your system (some other sx site might be more appropriate, but, generally: Win-R – cmd – enter the commands and look for output) for either:

- `latexmk`
- `arara`.

Both let you automatize your LaTeX processing, in somewhat different ways. Basically, if you are able to run `latexmk`, you say `latexmk -pdf yourdocument.tex` (or even without file extension). The required number of `pdflatex` runs, the accompanying `bibtex` / `biber` runs, creating the glossary, all happens automatically.

If you don't have those installed, the typical routine is

- latex
- bibtex
- latex
- latex.

Only then you have a document with all the references and all the links.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the command `pdflatex` w/o any keys doesn't work for me properly. 
I mean, it works, but not generated `.pdf` files as well.

So, the one-line solution is already exist!

```
pdflatex -pdf yourname.tex
```

Comment: Really, `pdflatex -pdf`? Not `latexmk -pdf`? `$ pdflatex -pdf
pdflatex: unrecognized option `-pdf'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`

Comment: Unless the poster accidentally alias pdflatex to latexmk for some reason, but that should not happen.