# How to change formatting of table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, line-spacing, thesis

I am using isuthesis package for writing my thesis.

http://www.github.com/srvanderplas/Dissertation/blob/master/isuthesis.cls

I want my table of contents to have font size 14 and one and half line spacing.
Similarly List of table and List of Figures should have 14 font size and one and half line spacing.
Please suggest.

```
 % Template file for a standard thesis
    \documentclass[11pt]{isuthesis}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    % Standard, old-style thesis
    \usepackage{isutraditional}   \chaptertitle
    % Old-style, thesis numbering down to subsubsection
    \alternate

    %Optional Package to add PDF bookmarks and hypertext links
    \usepackage[pdftex,hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}
    \begin{document}


\include{preface/abstract}
% Table of Contents, List of Tables and List of Figures
\pdfbookmark[1]{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{table}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{}} \cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
% Comment out the next line if NOT using chaptertitle
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}

    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \include{Body/chapter1}

    %\include{Reference/biblio}
    \end{document}
```

below given is the chapter 1 code.

```
    % Chapter 1 of the Thesis Template File
\chapter{OVERVIEW}

This is the opening paragraph to my thesis which
explains in general terms the concepts and hypothesis
which will be used in my thesis.

With more general information given here than really
necessary.

\section{Introduction}

Here initial concepts and conditions are explained and
several hypothesis are mentioned in brief.

\subsection{Hypothesis}

Here one particular hypothesis is explained in depth
and is examined in the light of current literature.

\subsubsection{Parts of the hypothesis}

\begin{table}[h!tb] \centering
\setlength{\captionwidth}{3.5 in}
\isucaption{This table shows a standard empty table with
a limited captionwidth}
\label{nevermore}

\vspace{ 2 in}
\end{table}
Here one particular part of the hypothesis that is
currently being explained is examined and particular
elements of that part are given careful scrutiny.

% Below \subsubsection
% Sectional commands: \paragraph and \subparagraph may also be used

\subsection{Second Hypothesis}

\begin{table}[h!tb] \centering
\setlength{\captionwidth}{3.5 in}
\isucaption{This table shows a second standard empty table with
a limited captionwidth}
\label{nevermore}

\vspace{ 2 in}
\end{table}
Here one particular hypothesis is explained in depth
and is examined in the light of current literature.

\subsubsection{Parts of the second hypothesis}

Here one particular part of the hypothesis that is
currently being explained is examined and particular
elements of that part are given careful scrutiny.

\section{Criteria Review}

Here certain criteria are explained thus eventually
leading to a foregone conclusion.
```

Comment: Try something like `{\onehalfspacing
   \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
  \tableofcontents
 }` with `\usepackage{setspace}` on.

Comment: Cant use setspace package, as it gives error. When i tried the above given solution without setspace, it worked fine except linespacing.

Comment: The `isuthesis.cls` template could seriously benefit from some major clean-up and streamlining.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have to use *this* class file, drop it. Completely. You will run into more trouble. Please see [PhD dissertation: templates vs scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214920/phd-dissertation-templates-vs-scratch).

You can do something like this, but please, please don't.
`Isuthesis` implements parts of package setspace. It is a terrible mess.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{isuthesis}
\usepackage{isutraditional}   \chaptertitle
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@chapapp{}
\makeatother
\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont
\setstretch{1.3}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\endgroup

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{OVERVIEW}

This is the opening paragraph to my thesis which
explains in general terms the concepts and hypothesis
which will be used in my thesis.

With more general information given here than really
necessary.

\section{Introduction}

Here initial concepts and conditions are explained and
several hypothesis are mentioned in brief.

\subsection{Hypothesis}

Here one particular hypothesis is explained in depth
and is examined in the light of current literature.

\subsubsection{Parts of the hypothesis}

\begin{table}[h!tb] \centering
    \setlength{\captionwidth}{3.5 in}
    \isucaption{This table shows a standard empty table with
    a limited captionwidth}
    \label{nevermore}

    \vspace{ 2 in}
\end{table}
Here one particular part of the hypothesis that is
currently being explained is examined and particular
elements of that part are given careful scrutiny.


\subsection{Second Hypothesis}

\begin{table}[h!tb] \centering
    \setlength{\captionwidth}{3.5 in}
    \isucaption{This table shows a second standard empty table with
    a limited captionwidth}
    \label{nevermore}

    \vspace{ 2 in}
\end{table}
Here one particular hypothesis is explained in depth
and is examined in the light of current literature.

\subsubsection{Parts of the second hypothesis}

Here one particular part of the hypothesis that is
currently being explained is examined and particular
elements of that part are given careful scrutiny.

\section{Criteria Review}

Here certain criteria are explained thus eventually
leading to a foregone conclusion.
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the comment that `isuthesis` is a terrible mess.