# How to convert latex pdf into a word file?

Tags: pdf, convert, latex-to-word

I am using "Adolf Acrobats", and "I love PDF" to convert my thesis pdf  file into word format, but a lot of errors encountered in the converted word file. Like, Mathematical symbols or, equations, and footnotes etc. are  not properly converted.

Comment: https://pandoc.org/

Comment: Have you checked out the postings [How to convert a scientific manuscript from LaTeX to Word using Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111886/5001) and [Producing doc/docx from LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8836/5001)?

Comment: @Mico I am unable to install Pandoc in my windows 10. Would you please help me to install it using cmd command? The current directory of Pandoc in my system  is in C:\Programe Files\Pandoc.

Comment: @gete - I'm a Mac and MacOS person. I'm afraid I have virtually no experience installing or uninstalling anything on Windows. Sorry. Aside: Since the question of how to install Pandoc on a Windows10 system would appear to be off-topic for this site, you may want to re-post it on the [main Stack-Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site.

Comment: @Mico Ok.......