# Just curiosity about the 'LaTeX' name

Tags: latex-misc

It's common knowledge that the word 'TeX' was inspired by the Greek word 'τεχ' pronounced "tech".

Just for satisfying my curiosity, anyone knows from where comes the letters 'La' in LaTeX?

Comment: Leslie Lamport :)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex/28324#28324

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: This might look obvious, especially to mother-tongue English speakers, but I think we should mention it anyway: the name is (also) a pun with the English word [latex](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/latex).

Comment: In my opinion, LaTeX stands for Lazy TeX.  Therefore, it should be pronounced as "La" as Lazy rather than "La" as Last.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I remember the first time that I googled _beautiful latex_ in image search to find some good template. Probably I saw something relative to LaTeX at the 10th page. :)

Answer (score 21):

The word "LaTeX" is an abbreviation of "Lamport's TeX", named after Leslie Lamport. With LaTeX Lamport added a collection of macros to the original TeX program which was made by Donald Knuth.

Comment: I've always heard so and, in fact, I've always consider this to be the origin of the "La", but I've never seen an official source in which this is documented (by Lamport himself preferably). Do you happen to have such a source?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All I could find so far is an interview with Lamport by a German Mathematicians association (DMV) in which one question refers to that fact: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/lamport-latex-interview.pdf

Comment: I thought "La" simply means "larger", since "LaTeX" includes more macros than "TeX", hence "larger" Tex.

Comment: IMO the recent edit to this answer was pointless and shouldn't have been approved; the original version was fine (and better). (But I won't rollback and add to the noise.)

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that LA means (Logic of Actions) since that Lamport developed the Temporal Logic of Actions and the corresponding TLATex typeset system.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/tla/tlatex.html

However it's a pity that Lamport himself does not satisfy our curiosity.

Comment: Later Additions-TeX :P

Comment: @zedobone i have a feeling that lamport himself isn't a terribly forthcoming person; in my time in this lab i've known a couple of people "working with" him, and indeed i've worked on a book which iirc had him listed as co-author.  (once upon a time, we had m$ research as next-door neighbour of our lab, and i think i've worked at a desk this >> << close to his, but in different buildings.)

Answer (score 1):

@SFAB attributed that LaTeX is an abbreviation of "Lamport TeX" to [an interview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/latex-changed-face-mathematics/?from=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Flamport%2Fpubs%2Flamport-latex-interview.pdf). However, after scanning the publication of the interview, I don't find this information. (Does I miss it?)

After some search, I failed to find any [reliable source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reliable_sources) for the full phrase of LaTeX, just as @Gonzalo Medina mentioned in the comment.

I guess, just as Leslie Lamport refused to give the standard pronunciation of LaTeX[1], he also refused to give the correct full phrase of LaTeX.

### References

[1] In Lamport's book *LaTeX: A document Preparation System*:

> One of the hardest things about LaTeX is deciding how to pronounce it.This is also one of the few things I'm not going to tell you about LaTeX, since pronunciation is best determined by usage, not fiat.