# Where does the name "TeX" come from?

Tags: tex-history

I was reading about the etymology of the word *technology* and when I saw how tech is written in Greek, *τεχ*, the first thing came to my mind was TeX!

It seems so obvious but I couldn't find any information about the origin of TeX's name so here I ask.

Comment: How did this site survive all this time without this question being asked - and answered?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: BTW, I have always taken it for granted that "LaTeX" comes from "(Leslie) Lamport's TeX"; but where a positive reference to this can be found?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I found both your and my questions' answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64145/77323 (still not official btw.)

Comment: I think Lamport will never explicitly admit that he named his format after himself. ;-)  Almost certainly, the allure of the word “latex” (the rubber) played a rôle too.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'd rather quote Knuth himself (*The TeXbook*, page 1):

> English words like "technology" stem from a Greek root beginning with
>   the letters τεχ...; and this same Greek word means art as well as
>   technology. Hence the name TeX, which is an uppercase form of τεχ.
>
> Insiders pronounce the χ of TeX as a Greek chi, not as an "x", so that
>   TeX rhymes with the word blecchhh. It’s the "ch" sound in Scottish
>   words like loch or German words like ach; it’s a Spanish "j" and a
>   Russian "kh". When you say it correctly to your computer, the terminal
>   may become slightly moist.

After reading some comments to this answer, I think the following quote is also appropriate (it appear just one paragraph below the previous quote):

> On the other hand, it’s important to notice another thing about TeX's
>   name: The "E" is out of kilter. This displaced "E" is a reminder that
>   TeX is about typesetting, and it distinguishes TeX from other system
>   names. In fact, TEX (pronounced tecks) is the admirable Text EXecutive
>   processor developed by Honeywell Information Systems. Since these two
>   system names are pronounced quite differently, they should also be
>   spelled differently. The correct way to refer to TeX in a computer
>   file, or when using some other medium that doesn’t allow lowering of
>   the "E", is to type "TeX". Then there will be no confusion with
>   similar names, and people will be primed to pronounce everything
>   properly.

Comment: It is also worth to note that, at that time there was a text preparation system named **TEX** and the name **TeX** with the special logo also stated its difference to **TEX** – Similar in purpose but distinct in capabilities.

Comment: Then it should be ΤΕΧ [in Greek] or perhaps ΤεΧ rather than TeX ;-)

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald Yes, you're right. I've added the quesote about TEX from *The TeXbook*.

Comment: On the other hand, some of the “bad puns” on the name TeX contained in _The TeXbook_ assume the pronunciation “tecks”, _e.g.,_ “TeXture” on page 225.  (The index lists them all under “TeX, bad puns on”.)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think what it intends to say is that a correct pronounciation would exhale moist from your mouth and thus coat the terminal with a layer of moist. Not that the terminal would become moist by itself...

Comment: @Xiang Ji. Ofcourse... ofcourse......

Answer (score 4):

I dare to cite wikipedia: [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)

> The name TeX is intended by its developer to be /ˈtɛx/, with the final
>   consonant of loch or Bach.[50] The letters of the name are meant to
>   represent the capital Greek letters tau, epsilon, and chi, as TeX is
>   an abbreviation of τέχνη (ΤΕΧΝΗ – technē), Greek for both "art" and
>   "craft", which is also the root word of technical. English speakers
>   often pronounce it /ˈtɛk/, like the first syllable of technical.
>
> Donald Knuth instructs that it be typeset with the "E" below the
>   baseline and reduced spacing between the letters. This is done, as
>   Knuth mentions in his TeXbook, to distinguish TeX from other system
>   names such as TEX, the Text EXecutive processor (developed by
>   Honeywell Information Systems).[51] Fans like to proliferate names
>   from the word "TeX" – such as TeXnician (user of TeX software),
>   TeXhacker (TeX programmer), TeXmaster (competent TeX programmer),
>   TeXhax, and TeXnique.

It means `Technique` or `craft`, `ch` being written with `\chi` -- this is what D.E. Knuth had in mind and the art of electronic typesetting greek letters (and other things) is art and craft together.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a copy of the TeXBook by myself and I am too lazy to google for it right now, so I rather delete my apparently **totally unqualified** answer.