# How can I create a plain TeX macro that performs differently depending on whether or not it is called from within an \item?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I'd like to create a macro that behaves differently depending on whether or not it is called from within an `\item`, such as

```
\def\mymacro{\if<INSIDE_ITEM> do this \else do that\fi}
```

Here is an example where this could be used:

```
This is how my macro performs outside an item: {\mymacro}

\item{1}. And this is how it performs inside an item: {\mymacro}
```

For comparison, a similar situation regards macros that perform differently depending on whether or not they are called from within math mode, such as:

```
\def\anothermacro{\ifmmode do this \else do that\fi}
```

The trouble is that there does not seem to be any big difference between the environment of an item as compared to a normal paragraph.   Any ideas?

PS: I am really interested in *plain* TeX (as opposed to LaTeX)!  Also, a straightforward solution that does not require any extra packages would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `\item` in plainTeX is just `\par\hang\textindent`, with `\hang` is `\hangindent\parindent`. Such an `\item` AFAIK always ends with the next paragraph. So you could do `\ifdim\hangindent=\parindent … \else …\fi` as a heuristic. If you don't want a heuristic, you have to redefine `\item` (and maybe use `\everypar` to recognize the end of the item).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to what [cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277964/cabohah) suggested in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679837/how-to-create-a-plain-tex-macro-that-performs-differently-depending-on-whether-o/679846#comment1687007_679837), but with a small safety check: I redefine `\item` to use a new length `\itemindent` instead of `\parindent`, and set the former to be `\parindent` plus `1sp`. This is optically indistinguishable (just a couple of nanometers), but the chances of the test `\ifdim\hangindent=\itemindent` leading to a false positive are relatively small, I'd say.

```
\newdimen\itemindent
\itemindent\parindent
\advance\itemindent1sp
% the plain TeX definition is basically:
% \def\item{\par\hangindent\parindent\textindent}
\def\item{\par\hangindent\itemindent\textindent}
\def\mymacro{\ifdim\hangindent=\itemindent(INSIDE)\else(OUTSIDE)\fi}

Text text text text text text text text text \mymacro
\item{x} bla bla bla bla \mymacro
\item{x} bla bla bla bla \mymacro

Text text text text text text text text text \mymacro
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Both answers are great.  I'm accepting this one due to its greatest simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

Following the suggestion of cabohah in the comments:

```
\newif\ifinitem
\initemfalse
\def\mymacro{\ifinitem hi!\else bye\fi}
\def\item{\par\initemtrue\hang\textindent}
\let\oldpar\par
\def\par{\initemfalse\oldpar}
This is how my macro performs outside an item: {\mymacro}  

\item{1}. And this is how it performs inside an item: {\mymacro}

Now we are no longer inside the item: {\mymacro}
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Also, the etoolbox macros `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd` can manipulate booleans that way.

Comment: @rallg the OP asked for a solution with no packages, that's why I did it like this. Otherwise I might have opted for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79625/ which is an environment and therefore a bit easier to manipulate in terms of actions at the start and end.

Comment: +1 You could use the built-in `\endgraf` instead of making another copy of `\par`.

Comment: @Marijn OK, no packages. But the OP did not provide a MWE stating which packages were already used, and etoolbox is quite often used by a variety of standard packages. The environment approach is also very good.

Comment: @rallg The question states explicitly plain TeX.

Comment: @campa You are correct! I missed that. Never worked with plain TeX. Thought it had something to do with 8-track tapes.