# TeXstudio 2.5.2 User Commands not visible

Tags: fonts, xetex, texstudio

I am a newcomer to the world of LaTeX. After searching around on the net to see what others might think, I have installed `Tex Live 2012` and `TeXstudio 2.5.2`. I understand that now I have to setup my system somehow to display things properly, every time I compile my documents.

I have downloaded some examples, that actually compile and I can see the end result. The thing is that I would like to use the integrated Windows fonts (like Cambria or Calibri).

I have read somewhere that to do this I would need to use XeTeX, as it is able of Unicode Formatting(?, not sure). So the guide was mentioning that I would need to navigate to `Tools > User > User Commands > Edit User Commands` and make a new command named `XeTeX` that I could then use in `Options > Configure TeXstudio`.

The problem is that this submenu is not there! I navigate to `Tools > User` and nothing appears. Is that a bug or am I  doing something wrong?

This suggestion for Cambria and Calibri use is [here](http://www.theatreofnoise.com/2011/11/latex-tip-texstudio.html) , paragraph 5.
I am under Windows 7 x64 and I have installed everything in folders without spaces in their names. (I saw somewhere it really mattered!)

EDIT:
I have also installed version 2.5.1 and the latest SVN version (I don't know the difference :) ), but the menu is also not visible.

EDIT2:
OK, I'm pretty embarrassed... I found the user manual and there it is stated that User Commands are built from `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Build > Add user command`. When I navigate there, a window pops up with 2 columns, that you can `add` stuff. I guess it's something of a visual way to make macros instead of writing them. Is there a way to write them, then?

Comment: Do you actually want to use XeTeX or really XeLaTeX? XeLaTeX is available without a problem as a compiler. If you don't need XeLaTeX but XeTeX you can change the command for XeLaTeX to `xetex.exe` (→ Options → Configure TeXstudio → Commands). If you really want XeTeX as a user command you can create one in the Build section of the Configure TeXstudio window. This can be used in the Meta Commands section with `txs:///user` (for example). A shortcut can be assigned too.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel : Well, to tell you the truth I have no idea. I will try with XeLaTeX. The `User Commands` sub-menu is just the shortcut menu for all the user built commands!

Comment: The linked article uses the `xelatex.exe` but names the user command misleadingly “XeTeX”. If your document starts with `\documentclass` you use XeLaTeX and not XeTeX (→ [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49)), and then there’s no need to create a User Command.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you for your reply. I will try this and post the result asap!

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

you can use it with

User > User Commands > (ShortCut) or click on name

instead of using the edit button. Maybe that you have to restart texstudio after editing the user commands.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! The problem is that when I navigate to `Tools > User` there is nothing there! I cannot see User Commands!

Comment: did you a restart after editing the new user command

Comment: I cannot see the `User Command` to make a new one. That's the problem. :) Let me clarify. When I navigate to `Tools > Commands` I can see a submenu with things like : `Latexmk, latex...` etc. When I navigate to `Tools > User` there is nothing! No submenu. I am perplexed.

Comment: ok, I just saw that this is only available in an old version of TeXStudio. I'll install the newest version.

Comment: In the newest version (SVN 2.5.2), you create the command in `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Build`. Then look for the `User Commands` menu. Afterwards, you can see your custom commands sequences in `Tools > User`.

Answer (score 1):

`Option`->`Configure TeXstudio`->`Shortcuts`->`Menus`->`Tools`->`Commands`->`XeLaTeX`

Double click on the cell, intersection of `XeLaTeX` and `Current Shortcuts`