# TeX at the Command Line

Tags: tex-core

How does TeX work at the command line? More specifically, after having installed LaTeX, I found that typing `tex` in the command line opened up an interpreter. However, I have no idea what I can do here! If I type something like `\pi`, nothing happens! What does this TeX interpreter at the command line do?

Comment: You've said you installed LaTeX but then ran `tex` at the command line: which one are you aiming to use? (If that question doesn't make sense to you, take a look at [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49).)

Comment: Hit `enter` and then your `\pi` should give an error. Type "x" and hit enter to quit. If you type `\relax abc \bye` at the `**` prompt you will get a dvi with "abc" in it. If you start the whole experiment with `pdftex` you will get a pdf. If you type simply `abc` tex will try to find and open the file `abc.tex`.

Comment: @JosephWright I was aiming to mess around with TeX- just mentioning how I cam about installing it in case that was relevant.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll try when I get back to my computer. I wasn't getting an error though. I got one initial mathmode error, but then nothing. What does the \relax command do?

Comment: Well a mathmode *error* is an error, so you got an error. The \relax avoids that tex interprets the following text as file name.

Comment: The TeX interpreter reads an input file and processes it to make a DVI; if it is not given the name of an existing file, then it reads the file from "standard input," which is keyboard entry.

Comment: I see, sorry @UlrikeFischer what I was trying to say is that after the initial error, I didn't get anymore- despite typing the same thing. Thanks everyone!

Comment: `\relax` 'does nothing successfully'. It is a command you can give TeX when it expects to do something but you don't want it to.

Answer (score 11):

TeX is designed to read input either from a file or from the command line: indeed, if you have a file that doesn't properly end a TeX run you'll get the prompt wait for more input. When you start TeX at the prompt without giving it a file name, you'll get something like

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=tex)
**
```

where the two `*` are important. For this first prompt, TeX will try to look for a file name if you give just 'some text'. As such, it's normally safest to put `\relax` here (`\relax` is TeX's do-nothing command, so makes no change to the results).

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=tex)
**\relax

*
```

Notice that there is only one `*` now: TeX is no longer looking for a file name. Any input given is now treated in exactly the same way as if it were in a file. As we are talking about running `tex`, that means we use plain TeX syntax. We might therefore do

```
*Hello world

* $y = mx + x$.

*\bye
[1]
Output written on texput.dvi (1 page, 296 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

That will produce a `.dvi` file containing thext text `Hello world y = mx + c` with the formula in math mode. There will also be a page number as plain adds that automatically. You can then convert the `.dvi` to PDF format sing `dvips`/`ps2pdf` or `dvipdfmx`. (with no file name given, TeX default to the job name `texput`.)

As noted in a comment, running `pdftex` will give direct PDF output but otherwise the same process occurs. LaTeX can be run interactively with `latex` or `pdflatex`: the same considerations apply except the pre-defined control sequences are different.