# Tikz: Lighten whatever defined in fill style

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    particle/.style={%
    draw=none, 
    fill=blue, 
    circle, 
    minimum size=3mm
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[particle] at (0, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I had wanted the particle to have lighter blue fill I could have written:

```
\node[particle, fill=blue!20] at (0, 0) {};
```

But what if I change my fill color in global style (say to red)? Then I need to remember to change the above line to:

```
\node[particle, fill=red!20] at (0, 0) {};
```

My question: Is it possible to write something like `whatevercolor!20`?

Comment: You can define your own colour, i.e. `\definecolor{particlecolor}{RGB}{141,127,86}` and change the colour-value in the definition. Then you can lighten/darken the colour within a `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: Yes, that's a workaround.

Comment: If you don't mind the transparency effect, you can also use `opacity`.

Answer (score 8):

Using styles with arguments is one way to do this.

[image]

A possible way is :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    particle/.style=
    {
      draw=none, 
      fill=blue!#1, 
      circle, 
      minimum size=3mm
    },
    particle/.default=100,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[particle] at (0, 0) {};
    \node[particle=70] at (1, 0) {};
    \node[particle=40] at (2, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @blackened Someone (you ?) un-upvoted then downvoted, so I revert back... Any feedback instead of getting mad ?

Comment: (not me, I just upvoted) but could be someone using a tablet. The upvote/downvote are quite itchy and it's easy to mis-touch, and then the thing locks during a time. It happened to me at other times...

Comment: @marsupilam I downvoted (now re-upvoted) because I think this version is better.

Answer (score 3):

Within `tikz`, there is an emulation of the `xcolor` package that enables similar functionality when it comes to defining colours. (The `pgf` manual, section 15.2, helpfully points out that the emulation is extremely basic). It works well enough for LaTeX.

> For plain TEX users, it is not so easy to specify colors since plain
>   TEX has no “standardized” color naming mechanism. Because of this, pgf
>   emulates the xcolor package, though the emulation is extremely basic
>   (more precisely, what I could hack together in two hours or so).

According to the manual, gray and rgb colour models are supported. The colour you define can be lightened or darkened by using `!<number>`. The number expresses a percentage and ranges from `[0,200]`, with `0` being white and `200` being black. A few colours are pre-defined. Example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{104,120,54}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[mycolor!50] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[mycolor!100] (1,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
\fill[mycolor!150] (2,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three colours via tikz]

Comment: That applies to plain TeX, you and the OP uses LaTeX, and then TikZ uses `xcolor` directly, no emulation needed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Then the manual (3.0.1a) is outdated, it still states that emulates, not loads.

Comment: No, you've misunderstood. The emulation only kicks in if you're using the plain TeX format (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49 for reference), when you're using the LaTeX format, `xcolor` is loaded. The passage you quote explicitly says *For plain TeX users ...* Further, look in the `.log` file you get from your example and you'll see that `xcolor.sty` is read. See also section 8.1 in the manual. Or see the source: `tikz.sty` does `\RequirePackage{pgf}`, which does `\RequirePackage{pgfcore}`, which does `\RequirePackage{xcolor}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I see, thanks for the clarification! It's good to know that I can use the full `xcolor` functionality.