# How does Latex compilers integrate packages into its existing core functions?

Tags: packages

An example:

If I don't want to number an equation within the `equation` environment, I need to do two things:

1. Load the `amsmath` package at the preamble.
2. Use the command `\nonumber` at the end of the equation.

Without the `amsmath` package, the compiler would not recognize the `\nonumber` command. As far as my understanding goes:

1. The `equation` environment is part of Latex's core functions, and there is no package needed to call the environment. Its code specifies that it will **always** number the equation within.
2. The `amsmath` package allows the use of the command '\nonumber'.

My confusion is that it seems like the `\nonumber` command has interfered with the `equation` environment.

More specifically, the `\nonumber` command must somehow have communicated with the `equation` environment because once a `\nonumber` command is executed, the next `equation` environment automatically adjusts the numbering.

I find this hard to understand because loading a package doesn't mean erasing the existing commands. Moreover, it doesn't seem to me that the `\nonumber` command could have modified the code of the `equation` environment.

My question is: How could the `equation` environment recognize an unnumbered equation, which was done by a separate package, and adjust its numbering accordingly? More generally, how are packages integrated into existing LaTeX core functionalities?

My question might not have expresses fully my confusion so any additional information would be appreciated.

Comment: *I find this hard to understand because loading a package doesn't mean erasing the existing commands. Moreover, it doesn't seem to me that the '\nonumber' command could have modified the code of the 'equation' environment.* — Neither of these statements is true. To include a package means to run arbitrary code (whatever exists in that page), and it most certainly can erase or modify existing commands and environments.

Comment: (Meant “package”, not “page”, in previous comment.) Also, unfortunately for your example, `\nonumber` is defined in LaTeX itself (in around the place where the `equation` example is defined), not in the `amsmath` package. (But in general the kind of thing you describe is quite possible; a package can simply redefine things that were defined by LaTeX or other packages.)

Comment: How about when loading a package having a command that was already defined in a different package and Latex notifies the error?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Btw, my compiler somehow would not recognize the \nonumber command without the {amsmath} package... Anyway, supposing my example is correct, then did you mean that the {amsmath} package might have erased the original ‘equation’ environment and rewritten a new environment with the same name that allows the use of the /nonumber command? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @TheOblivious - Please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/5001) for a discussion of the properties of various displayed-math environments. The discussion also touches how loading the `amsmath` package modifies the properties of the `equation` environment.

Comment: The premise of your question is untenable: There are no LaTeX "compilers". TeX is, at its heart, a macro expansion language. It provides various (generally very low-level) "primitive" instructions, and it provides methods for extending the program's capabilities by defining new macros. LaTeX is, basically, a very extensive collection of macros (and their close relative, environments), which build on and augment the primitive instructions. LaTeX packages, in turn, provide further macros, which can provide either new capabilities or modify existing macros.

Comment: Please also read the posting [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49/5001) and especially [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220496/5001), which discusses some aspects of the division of labor between (La)TeX engines, formats, and packages.