# Can a package overwrite the original commands in Latex?

Tags: packages

An example:

Without the `amsmath` package:

1. The `equation` environment numbers the equation automatically.
2. The `align` environment cannot be executed.

With the `amsmath` package:

1. `align` and `equation` work seamlessly in numbering equations: I can use `equation` to write my first two equations, and `align` to write my third equation, and Latex will still number them correctly.

My questions are:

1. Is the code for the command `equation` after loading the `amsmath` package still the same as it was before loading the package?
2. Moreover, if this is the case, then, in general, can loading different packages cause conflicts? And how do we avoid it?

Comment: isn't this identical to the question you just asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415590/how-does-latex-compilers-integrate-packages-into-its-existing-core-functions ?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "yes". The answer to number 2 is also "yes", see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/whats-the-right-order-when-loading-packages?rq=1, or rather the duplicate question, and the "Linked" questions in the right margin.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think they are truly identical. The previous question was broader and is not a yes/no question. It also did not have anything similar to the second part of this question.  Finally, this question is more about me confirming my understanding of how Latex handles packages, in this particular context. However, please correct if I am wrong. I am thinking of removing the previous question anyway since nobody has given me an answer so far due to a lot of incorrect statements made in that question.

Comment: I can't see any difference to be honest. As already stated in answers and comments on the previous question a package can redefine absolutely any part of latex. No harm of course to remove the older question if you think this one is phrased better.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you. How about the answer to number 1? (I know the answer to the title is yes, but number 1 is a bit different from the title).

Comment: the answer to q1 is that amsmath redefines equation (but that is unrelated to the comments you make about numbering

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wouldn't it have to redefine `equation` in order for `equation` to work with `align` seamlessly?

Comment: no not at all, it just needs to use the same `equation` counter (the redefinition is for other reasons, to make it work with `subequation` and as you noted before to adjust things so `\nonumber` (which is defined in core latex but only affects `eqnarray`) also affects `equation`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your explanation. Now I understand a bit more about how Latex works. Hopefully, I will not have to post more trivial questions like this one and the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everyone can redefine commands or environments. Such a redefinition changes the code. This can lead to conflicts or unwanted side effects. But normally package writers know this and try to avoid such conflicts -- after all nobody is forced to use a package that doesn't behave and break other code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x=4
\end{equation}

\renewenvironment{equation}
{\par\color{red}\Huge\centering}
{\par}

\begin{equation}
x=4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, it hurts my eyes!!! Not because the size or color, but because equation not in math mode :)

Answer (score 3):

A package can redefine any part of latex and produce arbitrary outcomes.

For example save this as `zzz.sty`

```
\everypar{}
BOO!
\stop
```

and add

```
\usepackage{zzz}
```

to any latex document.

The fact the `equation` and `align` number in sequence does not require a redefinition of either enviornment, this document defines a new envioenment `zzz` that numbers in the same sequence but does not redefine either `equation` or `align`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{zzz}
{\par\refstepcounter{equation} \fbox{this is \theequation zzz}}
{zzz ends here\par}

\begin{document}

equation
\begin{equation}
  1=1
\end{equation}

zzz
\begin{zzz}
  qqq
\end{zzz}

align
\begin{align}
  a&=1\\
b&=2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Packages can have irreconcilable conflicts if package a defines `\zzz` to be red and package b defines `\zzz` to be blue then you clearly can not have both packages working at the same time. If you load both packages depending on the implementation details you may get an error or you may get red or blue depending on package loading order. It is up to the author of the document to load the packages that are needed and not to load packages that conflict.