# Does LaTeX use METAPOST to generate pictures?

Tags: graphics, diagrams, metapost

This is a sort of continuation to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex).
I would like to know how does LaTeX generate pictures with its 'picture' 
environment. Since TeX deals with typesetting and not with graphics,
I suppose LaTeX uses METAPOST. So I guess once you ask it to compile,
LaTeX translates the 'picture' code into METAPOST. Am I correct?

Comment: Latex does not use metapost. Picture is a fairly simple construction (though I don't know the details). Why do you want to know? Picture is not really relevant nowadays when we have tikz/pgf. Though there are certain things that are a he'll of a lot easier to do in metapost that in tikz/pgf

Comment: I have 'developing' in the back of my mind, that's why I ask strange questions. I am not that interested in 'driving the car' than knowing how does it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard picture mode places lines and small arcs and circles by using fonts with the relevant pieces. That is the reason for the slightly weird line syntax where you specify a fixed slope and a horizontal length, the slopes are constrained to the slopes of the available line segments in the fonts.

There are re-implementations for picture mode using pdf or postscript specials that allow a wider range of slopes and circles of larger sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any documentation about the internal works of 'picture' environment and the like? Where can I get detailed information?

Comment: @Lagrange.el.Ciencia yes sure: `texdoc source2e` or online at https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e  chapter D ltpictur (page 343)