# On TeX and LaTeX relations

Tags: macros, tex-core, dvi

Could you help me with the following questions?

1. I have downloaded the source files of MiKTeX of the last version and I want to see the source code of `latex.exe` but cannot find it. Where is it located?
2. When I process my `.tex` file into a `.dvi` file via `latex.exe` then what exactly this program does? Does it use "virgin" TeX? It is said that LaTeX is a set of macros based on TeX. For example, pure TeX does not know environments. When I compile my LaTeX file containing environments then are they translated into pure TeX (maybe taken from format files?) and then processed by `tex.exe` (or by something like a TeX core)? [If TeX has `tex.exe` and LaTeX has `latex.exe`, then what is the dependence of LaTeX on TeX?]
3. Am I right that the relations between TeX and LaTeX are somewhat like pure C and a library in C language so you can just use already defined functions and not to touch the low-level stuff?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex/85#85 Perhaps?

Comment: Why do you contemplate compiling your .tex file to a .dvi file? Compiling straight to .pdf is the default nowadays the default with all major TeX engines (though not with "Knuth TeX").

Comment: @Mico: It’s easy for beginners to end up using dvi — many older introductions/tutorials prescribing dvi still get recommended to newcomers either just from inertia or because they’re good tutorials in other ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex)