# Curly braces of arbitrary size

Tags: braces

How to get a curly brace of given length? (e.g: 100px)

The following works but it is obviously not the best solution:

```latex
\begin{cases}
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\end{cases}
```

Answer (score 1):

By mirroring how `\Big` and similar existing LaTeX commands are defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
\left\{\vbox to 100pt{}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Output is as you expect.

Comment: Side note, use https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4327/250119 to find out how something is defined. In this case latexdef suffices

Answer (score 1):

Here are two macros that take a length as an argument. Note that these are not "paired" in the sense that you can use `\biggglB` without a matching `\bigggrB`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\biggglB}[1]{\left\{\!\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{#1}}\right.}
\newcommand{\bigggrB}[1]{\left.\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{#1}}\!\right\}}

\begin{document}

\[
\biggglB{70pt}ABC\bigggrB{50pt}\Biggl\{ABC\Biggr\}\{ABC\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\leftbrace[1]{\mathopen  {\raisebox{+2pt}{%
  \,\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\hbox to #1{\upbracefill}}\,}}}
\newcommand\rightbrace[1]{\mathclose{\raisebox{-2pt}{%
  \,\rotatebox[origin=c]{+90}{\hbox to #1{\upbracefill}}\,}}}
\begin{document}
$\leftbrace{100pt}XxxX\rightbrace{10pt}-1$
\end{document}
```

[image]